# creating outlets ,modal ,sague , actions by drag and drop not working while connecting thru teamviewer in xcode

Tags: xcode, teamviewer

I am creating xcode programming for iphone using swift language . I am working on windows and connecting mac system thru teamviewer. while creating outlets or actions or modals or sague the drag and drop feature not working. I have to manually write the codes for that. Also movement of scenes in storyboard for alignment not working by dragging.

can anyone  tell me what is the solution?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622012/xcode-storyboard-doesnt-work-over-vnc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are facing right click problem same as me .
Try this ,

**Go to:**

```
TeamViewer preferences: option Advanced ==> use control and mouse-

click as right mouse click.check that box
```

And then try.

**Edit:-** You can also check this youtube link.

[Teamviewear right click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuXOGpmmSXw)

**Edit:-** Screenshot for preferences

[image]

Comment: will you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes. Actually this is common problem in teamviewear when you accessing in mac then right click is not working. So, you can do process with respectively to right click. so , just enable it from preferences and then try.

Comment: no such options 'preferences' in team viewer.' Extra' option is there , in that Advanced option is there but no such options to change mouse button  controls

Comment: can you give me screenshot where you are checking ?

Comment: thanks for the reference . Actually at the first i have tried in my windows teamviewer . But still same problem .. not solved yet..

Comment: have you close and run again teamviewear ?

Comment: solution not yet recovered

Comment: after restarting teamviewer same problem is there. is there is another method to use drag and drop feature or create outlets or sague in xcode @Badal Shah

Comment: nope this method only works. you can also check in teamviewear official forums and it also worked for me . http://teamviewerforums.com/index.php?topic=1886.0

Comment: hey this solution is  for when i m using mac nd connecting to windows. in my case i m using windows and connect to mac system thru teamviewer

Comment: same solution for visaversa. my scenario is like you and worked with me .

Comment: you are using external mouse or inbuilt ? try using external mouse.